# How can I get the feed of a single question?

Tags: support, questions, feed

There are some nice threads like [this on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271398/what-are-your-favorite-extension-methods-for-c-codeplex-com-extensionoverflow?rq=1)  where I only want to get updates when a new answer gets added.

Is there any feature like that ?

Comment: You could favor that question and see updates in your favorite list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every question has an RSS feed that you can find by scrolling all the way to the bottom of the page:

---

> [image: screenshot]

---

However, the question you linked to is locked, so a feed would be entirely useless since no new answers can be added at all. Therefore, the feed link is not shown.

Comment: ah ok.. i wasn't aware that we cant add answer to locked question.. thanks for the answer